# Special search and replace

Tags: substitute

How can I search and replace `array[j]` by `array` in the whole script?

I tried `:%s/array[j]/array/` but that does not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the brackets, as they are special characters used to indicate a list in a substitution.

Your command should be `:%s/array\[j\]/array/g`

Comment: I still get a " pattern not found" error message.

Comment: Do you actually mean to replace only the ones with j - array[j]? Maybe you can paste some parts of the script so we can try on our machines.

Comment: @ALBERTOEDGARCHAVARRIARODRIG If you're getting that message, then the pattern is either not in the file, or you are not escaping it properly. As Neatu suggests, you should post part of the file where you're trying to do the substitution.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my script https://www.dropbox.com/s/5w41dv1bg2x4mpo/search.png?dl=0. Please have a look.

Comment: @ALBERTOEDGARCHAVARRIARODRIG Please edit your question to include a sample of the text from your file.